# a limit calculation problem?

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function

how to calculate this?

$\lim_{t \to \infty}(\frac{2^t+5^t}{4})^\frac{1}{t}$

Answer (score 3):

$$\left(\frac{2^t+5^t}{4}\right)^{\frac{1}{t}}=5\left(\frac{0.4^t+1}{4}\right)^{\frac{1}{t}}\rightarrow5$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{2^t+5^t}4\right)^{1/t}$$

$$=\dfrac5{\lim_{t\to\infty}4^{1/t}}\left[\lim_{t\to\infty}\left(1+(2/5)^t\right)^{(5/2)^t}\right]^{\lim_{t\to\infty}(2/5)^t/t}$$

Now using L'Hospital's, $\lim_{t\to\infty}\dfrac{(2/5)^t}t=0$

and we know $\lim_{t\to\infty}\left(1+(2/5)^t\right)^{(5/2)^t}=e$

Answer (score 0):

Using the Squeeze Theorem:
$$5^{t-1}<\frac{2^t+5^t}{4}<5^t \Rightarrow$$
$$5=\lim_{t\to\infty} 5^{\frac{t-1}{t}}\le\lim_{t\to\infty} \left(\frac{2^t+5^t}{4}\right)^{\frac1t}\le\lim_{t\to\infty} 5^{\frac{t}{t}}=5$$